# Hot reload button disabled in android and CTRL+S is not working

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, hot-reload

I have installed the android studio and make all the setup to run flutter application all done good but since I installed all this setup hot reload button on the top bar is disabled.

I restarted IDE but it did not work CTRL+S is not working in my case because hot reload button is unclickable.
Error connecting to the service protocol: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://127.0.0.1:59005/1rJS68FLV5A=/ws this is the new type of error I have seen so maybe the issue is due to this but I am not sure about it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMthA.png)

Answer (score 0):

can you please upgrade the flutter and dart version